# How to delete property from dynamic JObject programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, deserialization

Below is the code

json - just want JsonLookupData in the response

```
{
  "LookupType": "ABC",
  "BusSegmentName": "Test",
  "PolcyObjectId": "999",
  "JsonLookupData": {
    "data":    {
      "OBJ_ID": "9393",
      "ABC": "JAJA",
      "XYZ": "LL",
      "AAA": "250.00"
    }
  }
}

public new dynamic input { get; set; }

//initialization 
 input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonInput.ToString());

//trying to remove all attributes except JsonLookupData
input.Properties().Where
                 (x => !x.Name.Equals("JsonLookupData")).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
```

Is there any way to delete the properties directly from the dynamic **input** (Don't want to assign it to JObject first).

above code is giving the below error

```
Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
```

Comment: What does the sample JSON look like?

Comment: @DavidL hi , i have updated the JSON

Comment: Why do you use `dynamic`? You can deserialize to `JObject` or `JToken`.

Comment: Is this a theoretical exercise? It makes no sense to use dynamic as the intermediary instead of a JObject.

Comment: @DavidL this is the pattern already used in creating all the scripts, I think going by this pattern only way to achieve this is explicitly removing irrelevant properties like input.Property("BusSegmentName").Remove();  etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a JObject is still the right choice, you can still use `dynamic` as long as you do not use lambda expressions that are reliant on dynamic dispatch.

By assigning the output of `input.Properties()` to a non-dynamic type (`IEnumerable<dynamic>`), we can perform operations in a lambda expression.

```
input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonInput.ToString());

IEnumerable<dynamic> props = input.Properties();
props.Where(x => !x.Name.Equals("JsonLookupData")).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());

string xx = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
```

This outputs:

```
{"JsonLookupData":{"data":{"OBJ_ID":"9393","ABC":"JAJA","XYZ":"LL","AAA":"250.00"}}}
```

---

Alternatively, you can avoid Linq altogether.

```
input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonInput);

// create a separate tracking collection so that we 
// do not modify the collection we are iterating
var propsToRemove = new List<JProperty>();

foreach (var prop in input.Properties())
{
    if (!prop.Name.Equals("JsonLookupData"))
    {
        propsToRemove.Add(prop);
    }
}

propsToRemove.ForEach(x => x.Remove());

string xx = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
```

This outputs:

```
{"JsonLookupData":{"data":{"OBJ_ID":"9393","ABC":"JAJA","XYZ":"LL","AAA":"250.00"}}}
```

for your sample JSON.

Comment: will the value of input remain intact (JsonLookupData part) ? if we do JToken.FromObject(input);  will i get the desired output ?

Comment: Do you want the input to remain intact? You did not mention anything along these lines in your original question. And yes, you can do a JToken/JObject.FromObject, but again, these answers were in line with your request to not use a JObject.